# Как провалидировать расширение и размер файла в FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Возникла необходимость провалидировать расширение и размер файла, однако, возникли сложности. Есть два варианта.

## Вариант 1. Dependency injection

```
app = FastAPI()


class FileExtensionValidator:
    message = 'Extension “{extension}” not allowed. Allowed extensions are {allowed_extensions}'

    def __init__(self, allowed_extensions=None, message=None):
        if allowed_extensions is not None:
            allowed_extensions = [allowed_extension.lower() for allowed_extension in allowed_extensions]
        self.allowed_extensions = allowed_extensions
        if message is not None:
            self.message = message

    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile):
        extension = Path(file.filename).suffix[1:].lower()
        if self.allowed_extensions is not None and extension not in self.allowed_extensions:
            detail = self.message.format(extension=extension, allowed_extensions=', '.join(self.allowed_extensions))
            raise HTTPException(400, detail=detail)


class MaxFileSizeMBValidator:
    def __init__(self, max_mb: int):
        self.max_mb = max_mb

    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile):
        if file.size / 1024 / 1024 > self.max_mb:
            message = f'Maximum file size exceeded'
            raise HTTPException(400, detail=message)


@router.post(
    '/upload/',
    dependencies=[
        Depends(MaxFileSizeMBValidator(max_mb=1)),
        Depends(FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['.docx'])),
    ]
)
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile, user_id: int = Form()):
    return {'filename': file.filename}
```

Минусы данного варианта в том, что не возвращаются все ошибки валидации, тк как только будет выброшено исключение HTTPException, то FastAPI вернет ответ, а остальное не будет провалидировано. Так, например, если в запросе не будет передан `user_id`, то он не будет провалидирован и вернется ответ:

```
{
    "detail": "Extension “csv” not allowed. Allowed extensions are .docx"
}
```

Как видим, отработала самая первая объявленная зависимость. Я бы хотел получить ответ:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "file"
            ],
            "msg": "Extension “csv” not allowed. Allowed extensions are .docx",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        },
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "user_id"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Можно это сделать?

## Вариант 2. Переопределение UploadFile.

Посмотрел исходный код FastAPI, я узнал, что можно [переопределить метод `__get_validators__`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/f7e3559bd5997f831fb9b02bef9c767a50facbc3/fastapi/datastructures.py#L21):

```
class CustomUploadFile(UploadFile):
    validators = [
        MaxFileSizeMBValidator(max_mb=10),
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['.docx']),
    ]

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls: Type["UploadFile"]) -> Iterable[Callable[..., Any]]:
        yield cls.validate

        for validator in cls.validators:
            yield validator
```

Но так придется каждый раз переопределять, а хочется как в Django как то так:

```
file = serializers.FileField(
    label='Файл для загрузки',
    validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'tif', 'psd']),
        MaxFileSizeMBValidator(max_mb=50),
    ],
)
```

Можно как то так сделать?

Comment: Почему не пользуетесь pydantic validation?

Comment: https://nsantoshgokul.medium.com/complex-request-validation-in-fastapi-with-pydantic-%EF%B8%8F-ef2fd297dda2

Comment: Попробуйте как в ссылке выше. Там подход более правильный. И будет у вас всё выводится как вам надо.

Comment: @Exord, прошу прощения, но я не понял, как сделать как там. UploadFile - это ведь не модель Pydantic, а наследник старлеттовского UploadFile